# Magento 2 Order customer group id

Tags: magento, magento2

In magento 2. Whatever the customer group id is order customer group id is always default. For example if customer group is paid but when he place the order then order customer group is default.

Can you please help me whether it is a magento 2 bug? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Magento2 Enterprise edition 2.1.1. Every customer information have the checkbox "Disable Automatic Group Change Based on VAT ID" If it is unchecked then after every order customer group update. It's further details are at

http://docs.magento.com/m1/ee/user_guide/tax/vat-validation-manage.html

I hope it will save the time for someone. Please vote my answer if it will save your time. Thank you.